# How to update value in only 1st top row of a table in specific column using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am working on a desktop application in C#. I am very new to SQL Server.

First of all I would like apologize for the question I am asking may be relevant to the questions asked before on this topic, but I searched on the internet and did not find any answer for the problem.

There is a table in my database named `BillingTemp`. Columns are

```
Bill No, Package, Type, DiscPer, TotalAmt, BillDate, TaxAmt
```

`BillNo` may repeat as there are multiple entries in a specific bill.

Now on a button click, `TotalAmt` and `type` values in this table should be updated in only first row of a table as per my logic in the code.

How can I do this? Can anyone suggest query for this?

Comment: Could you please include the logic in your code?  If not, you will need to research using `top` and `order by` in your SQL scripts.

Comment: i need to move this data to another table and then this table would be empty for new bill entry. if every row of TotalAmt in the data table is affected then my calculation for sum of TotalAmt column will go wrong way.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to update only the 1st row in the table. Any way try LIMIT 1 eg : update BillNo set TotalAmt = 'value' , type = 'value' Limit 1

Comment: @VaibhavYadav whats the logic for the new values of Type and TotalAmt, So I can assist

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH TOP1 AS 
( 
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE BillNo = @BillNo
ORDER BY ID -- I assume you always want to update the record created first 
) 
UPDATE TOP1 SET TotalAmt =@TotalAmt , type = @type
```